# Shell script using `trap` sends output to next terminal prompt

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have the following shell script for running my server (Celery and FastAPI server).

```
# Start child processes
poetry run python run_celery.py &
pid_celery=$!
poetry run uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 server:server_app --reload &
pid_server=$!

# Function to cleanup child processes
cleanup() {
    echo "Cleaning up child processes"
    kill "$pid_celery" "$pid_server" # kill child processes
    wait "$pid_celery" "$pid_server"
}

# Trap SIGINT signal and cleanup child processes
trap cleanup SIGINT

# Wait for child processes to complete
wait "$pid_celery" "$pid_server"
```

When I press ⌃C, the process outputs "Cleaning up child processes" and exits but then the next shell prompt is pre-populated with output from the FastAPI process.

```
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [21303]
INFO:     Stopping reloader process [21296]
```

How should I modify my script so that it fully waits before child processes are finished/done printing?